# Drupal 8 migrate taxonomy hierarchy

Tags: taxonomy, drupal-8, migrate, drupal-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

How to migrate taxonomy terms along with parent terms using Migrate API.

id  parent  child
1   P1  C1
2   P1  C2

As above, P1 has 2 child C1 and C2.

How can the migrate api be used to create config file to get the import?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to take care about taxonomy and wich version you try to migrate. you got a possibility but you need to read the documentation and install it if you didn't got yet, extension here https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_import requirement drupal version 8. You can and need to manager your site install drush if shell prompt doesn't care you :).

Comment: Yes @headmax, this helped me. I was looking at migrate API only, didn't even think of module. Solved the issue. Thanks